# textarea save wont save with breakline

Tags: asp.net

I have a textarea and then I want to present it.
I want the text will be saved with the same break lines or \n.

but it wouldnt.

heres my code :

```
string content = Request.Form["content"];
          content =  System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(content);
          UpdateContent(content, id);

 public void UpdateContent(string content, string id)
{
    sql = "Update TBL_ZAC_SQUARES SET lotstext =@lotstext where id = " + id;

    connection = new SqlConnection(conn);
    connection.Open();

    cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lotstext", content);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    connection.Close();
}
```

then I present it like that :

```
<td align="right" style="padding: 12px; font-family: Arial; font-size: 12pt; color: #000000">
                                        <div >     <%=dt_details.Rows[0][9].ToString() %></div>
                                        </td>
```

Comment: What's the value saved in the DB?

Comment: a text.  that will be saved with user returns (br? or \n? )  it saved, but present it without the \n or br whatsoever

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are encode your content Before Saving In Database so you have to decode it before Showing in your Page///...So you Can Try like this...

```
 <div ><%=System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(dt_details.Rows[0][9].ToString()) %></div>
                                        </td>
```

and Before Encoding `content` Write...

```
content=content.Replace(Enviroment.NewLine,"<br/>");
```

Comment: Im just trying to write for example.. "hi.." (then I type enter or return)" how you doin?"

Comment: thank you .
it helped :) I wonder if you could edit your answer

Comment: option 1: replace your text "\r\n" with <br/> before saving it to databse. option 2: save it as it is in database. now if you want to display the text in textarea, then display it as it is with text containing \r\n or if you want to display it in any literal or label control then replace "\r\n" with <br/>.

Comment: @QasimJavaidKhan can't get u